# Group roles do not work in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I created several login and group roles in pgadmin. I then added these login roles to their respective group roles. Then I give these group roles login privileges to a database as well as other required privileges.

But connecting to the database fails with "User does not have CONNECT privilege".

Then I grant login privileges directly to the login roles in pgsql, because pgadmin does not let me add privileges to login roles, only group roles.

Now the user is able to connect to the database, but still gets various privilege errors until I give privileges directly to the login role.

Is this a bug in PostgreSQL (v 9.4.5 for Windows), or what is going on here? I also tried to add privileges to group roles using pgsql instead of pgadmin, with same results.

```
CREATE ROLE user_g
  NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;

CREATE ROLE user_l LOGIN
  ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'md5...'
  NOSUPERUSER NOINHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;
GRANT user_g TO user_l;

GRANT ALL ON DATABASE db TO postgres;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE db TO user_g;
REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE db FROM public;
```

Above statements do not give user_l privileges to connect to the database, but following does.

```
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE db TO user_l;
```

The problem then repeats for functions and everything else that requires privileges.

Comment: Show us the SQL statements you used to create the roles, the users and how you granted them.

Comment: *"Then I give these group roles login privileges..."* PostgreSQL doesn't have a GRANT LOGIN statement. It *does* have GRANT CONNECT, though, which seems relevant given the error message.

Comment: I have added the relevant sql statements as repprted by pgadmin to the question.